# Why can't I connect to my Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am following this guide to gain some experience in Dynamics 365:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/simple-program-web-services

Under Prerequisites I downloaded the Quick Start Sample and followed all steps. At one Point I need to sign in with my credentials I created for my 30-days Trial Dynamics 365 Site. I get an Unauthorized Access Exception.

Why? Do I need to configure something in my Dynamics 365 Site?

The Project: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sample-Quick-start-for-650dbcaa

My Inputs:

Enter a CRM Server Name and port: **crm.dynamics.com**

Is this organization privisioned...: **y**

Enter Username: **[my test@test.onmicrosoft.com email]**

Enter Password: **[my Password for this account]**

PS: I am an complete starter and need to do this for my boss. I don't have any Knowledge about Dynamics 365 I just need to create some Kind of example Project so my boss sees how this Framework works.

Comment: Are you able to access Dynamics 365 in browser with same credentials?

Comment: Yes I can. This is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SDK versión, the example could had been made before the CRM version your are trying to reference, have in mind that the SDK versión are Forward Compatible not Backward Compatible

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/02/01/dynamics-365-sdk-backwards-compatibility/

Hope it Helps